# Automatically Google Search from JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a website that advertises all of my YouTube videos, with quicklinks to my videos and social media. I do want a search function but I don't want the hastle of messing about with plugins and PHP or Java Servlets or ASP.NET. I have seen you can use Google to do this for you by searching {term} site:{site to search}. How would I go about doing this from JavaScript? I am already storing the user's input from the search box in a variable in JS. How would I go about entering this into Google automatically without any plugins. Purely JavaScript and HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send a form to `http://www.google.com/search` with a field called `q` with the text of the search. You'll probably want to capture the form's `submit` event so you can add the `site:xxxx` part before submitting the form; that's the only JavaScript involved, the rest is just a `<form>` element.

Of course, using `www.google.com` means you'll be sending people to the U.S. site, as opposed to their country-specific site (if any).

Comment: OP could use a third party IP WHOIS service to retrieve country based on IP address and then use the result within a switch to determine which version of google to search within.

Comment: My site can only be viewed in English so to be honest I don't mind about the localization problem.

Comment: @odixon: I will just point out that there are `google.com`, `google.ca` (Canada), `google.co.uk` (United Kingdom), `google.com.au` (Australia), `google.co.nz` (New Zealand)... ;-) But as you're doing a site search, the distinctions really don't matter much.